# Failed to load extension from:

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I get the below message from Chromedriver while automating a web page download.
 "Failed to load extension from: ..... Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator"

If i click "OK" on the message, everything goes through as expected. Is there a way i can ignore this message (by automating a click on "OK" button / supress this box) so that remaining part of the script can go through.

I have added all the below options but none helped

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox");
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080");
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu");
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions");
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
```

I am using Python 3.6 on windows 10 x64bit

Comment: Hello Rajesh, welcome to StackOverflow! I saw you repeated the line `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions");` was that intentional?

Comment: That was not intentional but without that also it wasnt working.

Comment: chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

Comment: Got it fixed by adding the below line

Comment: Hey Rajesh, it's great you got your problem fixed. It would be nice, if you add your solution as an answer and accept it, so others see the solution if they have a similar problem.